# Regex string to numerical value (with extra characters not needed)

Tags: regex, monitoring, snmp, extract

I need to extract via Regex a numeric value from a string but I'm facing an issue with a character.

Here is the style of string I get:

```
XC.qca955x.v7.2.4.31259.160714.1715
```

The goal is to get : 7.24

Right now I'm using `\d+\.\d+` which gives me: 7.2

I am lacking the extra 4.

The final extraction can only be interpreted as a numeric value so I need to add the last digit without a point.

Is this even possible with Regex?

Thank you very much for any support.

Comment: Can you *replace* with a regex? You could use [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/MKUIuB/1). Else, no, one cannot match discontinuous/non-adjoining texts with one regex match operation.

Comment: What is the tool are you using?

Comment: PRTG, but I guess that it's not feasable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which language you are using, but here are 2 solutions for your problem.
First you could use 2 capturing groups, then concatenate them :
`\.v(\d+\.\d+)\.(\d+)`
then concatenate $1 and $2 (group 1 and group 2)
You can also take the point,  then remove it, using the right function in your language :
`\.v(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)`
Then replace in $1 (group 1) `(.*)\.(\d+)$` by `$1$2`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'm not actualy programming, this issue come from a monitoring program.

I basicaly pull this string from the device via SNMP, then the monitoring program allow me to do some "processing" on this string to extract a numeric value via a Regular Expression.

I see that it could work well via the substitution but I'm not abble to set that on the monitoring program, I can only select a capturing group.
This is why this look no feasable.

Comment: You can't select both capturing groups then concatenate them ?